# Is there any way to have the prompt variable only executed once within this loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm building this etch-a-sketch project and I have a 64x64 grid I have created through a 'for' loop. I want to have a function associated with a button I have at the top to:

1. Clear the page for a fresh grid
2. Prompt the user to enter a new value (i.e. 20x20, 40x40)

Only problem I have is that if the prompt is within this loop, it will prompt 256 times. How do I make it to where it asks the user only once and then the pop up goes away?

JavaScript Code:

```
for(x = 0; x < 256; x++){
            let clearPage = document.getElementById('btn-clear')
            let squares = document.createElement('div');
            squares.className = 'grid-square';
            container.appendChild(squares);

            //on-click event to get the etch started
            squares.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
                squares.style.cssText = 'background: yellow';
            })

                //btn function
                clearPage.addEventListener("click", function(){      
                squares.style.cssText = 'background: #eee';
                let newGrid = prompt('Please enter new grid dimensions ranging from 2 through 100', ' ');
            })
            
        }

        
    }
    gridSquares();
```

HTML:

```
<input id="btn-clear" type="button" value="Start Over!">
<br>
<div id="container">
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 98vh;
    display: grid;
    border: 0.25px; solid black;
    /*background: #eee;*/
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
}

.grid-square {
    border: 0.25px solid black;
    background: #eee;

}

#btn-clear {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to move the click listener of element#btn-click out of the for-loop, and then to reset all the squares style.

```
// for (;;) {}
document.getElementById('btn-clear').addEventListener('click', () => {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementById('container').children, item => item.style.cssText = 'background: #eee')
  // then prompt and do sth
  let newGrid = prompt('Please enter new grid dimensions ranging from 2 through 100', ' ')
})
```